Ansible play fails while printing variable with error - task includes an option with an undefined variable
I have a shell task in Ansible that plays between an if-else condition. Under the if condition it prints echo on 2 lines while in the else condition it prints a single line.
I need a generic debug print statement that prints for both if and else condition.
- name: Extract certificate or key information
  shell: >     
    if [[ "{{ certlocation }}" != *.key ]]; then
      cert_cn=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -subject -nameopt sep_multiline)
      echo "~$cert_cn"
      cert_san=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -ext subjectAltName)
      echo "~$cert_san"
    else
      cert_san=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -ext subjectAltName)
      echo "~$cert_san"   
    fi
  register: cert_info
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: Print specific information
  debug:
    msg: |
      cert_cn: "{{ cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1] | default('NA') }}"
      cert_san: "{{ cert_info.stdout_lines[1].split('~')[1] | default(cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1]) }}"

I tried the above but it fails with the below error during the else condition which prints a single line:
TASK [Print specific informations] ***************************************************************************************************************************Monday 29 July 2024  23:51:46 -0500 (0:00:00.022)       0:00:00.517 ***********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: list object has no element 1\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/wladmin/teststdoutlines.yml': line 17, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Print lines using index from stdout_lines\n      ^ here\n"}

I was expecting upon failure that it would default to cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1] which has a valid value.
Once the debug works, I wish to apply the same solution to set_facts to assign the values to variables.
How can I handle such cases in Ansible?

If you are still on a really outdated version of Ansible, like I remember it from your previous question, you probably have to add default at different locations, because it wasn't working that well previously. So probably rather something like(cert_info.stdout_lines[1] | default(cert_info.stdout_lines[0])).split('~')[1] or something like that. Another possible cause of this is that .split('~') return only one item, so it cannot access the 1 there. Either way, without a example output of cert_info.stdout_lines causing the issue, that's possibly the best you'll get of an answer.

Here,first of all you need to define a variable in ansible playbook and you can define a variable in three ways.

mention variable in ansible playbook
mention variable in extra vars while running playbook
mention variable using set_fact in ansible playbook
Hence you can apply a solution like this in three ways.



- name: extract key information
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    certlocation: "/path/to/your/keyfile"
  tasks:
    - name: Extract certificate or key information
      shell: >     
        if [[ "{{ certlocation }}" != *.key ]]; then
          cert_cn=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -subject -nameopt sep_multiline)
          echo "~$cert_cn"
          cert_san=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -ext subjectAltName)
          echo "~$cert_san"
        else
          cert_san=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -ext subjectAltName)
          echo "~$cert_san"   
        fi
      register: cert_info
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Print specific information
      debug:
        msg: |
          cert_cn: "{{ cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1] | default('NA') }}"
          cert_san: "{{ cert_info.stdout_lines[1].split('~')[1] | default(cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1]) }}"


Now, second way is that you can define a variable in extra vars

ansible-playbook main.yml --extra-vars
"certlocation=/path/to/your/keyfile"

Hence, third way is like to define a variable using setfact like this
---
- name: extract key information
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:

    - name: Set certlocation
      set_fact:
        certlocation: "/path/to/your/certificate/or/key/file"

    - name: Extract certificate or key information
      shell: >     
        if [[ "{{ certlocation }}" != *.key ]]; then
          cert_cn=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -subject -nameopt sep_multiline)
          echo "~$cert_cn"
          cert_san=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -ext subjectAltName)
          echo "~$cert_san"
        else
          cert_san=$(openssl x509 -in "{{ certlocation }}" -noout -ext subjectAltName)
          echo "~$cert_san"   
        fi
      register: cert_info
      delegate_to: localhost

    - name: Print specific information
      debug:
        msg: |
          cert_cn: "{{ cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1] | default('NA') }}"
          cert_san: "{{ cert_info.stdout_lines[1].split('~')[1] | default(cert_info.stdout_lines[0].split('~')[1]) }}"

Like this you can define variable in three ways
